# Ruby Default Arguments: Static or Dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are default arguments in ruby methods static?  This matters when default arguments are meant to be a dynamic date, such as `Date.today`. Consider the following example in a rails application:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def eligible_to_vote?(date_of_interest = Date.today)
    p date_of_interest
  end

end
```

Will the default `date_of_interest` date always be the the same, static date from when I started the rails server?

Or: will it always dynamically grab "today's date" within the context of the date that the `eligible_to_vote?` method was called?

I know the following would for sure dynamically grab `Date.today`:

```
# Always dynamically sets `date` variable when no argument passed in
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def eligible_to_vote?(date_of_interest = nil)
    date = date_of_interest.present? ? date_of_interest : Date.today
    p date_of_interest
  end

end
```

What I'm mostly interested in is if default method arguments are dynamically generated or not.  Whatever the answer is, it would be nice to have some official reference to answer this question as well. Thanks!

Comment: Ruby is not compiled, it’s interpreted. Hence they are obviously dynamic. I doubt there is any official reference because it’s a trivial consequence of Ruby’s scripting nature.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I very well am probably misunderstanding you.  However, it sounds like you are saying that ruby doesn't look at the method definition at all until the method is actually called.  I do not think this is the case though.  Consider the following: `def 1!test; p 'test'; end`.    When you attempt to run this ruby script it errors out because it is looking at the method definition.  If this is true, then ruby is probably looking at the default argument in the method definition and statically setting it right along with the method's reference.

Comment: You mixed up lexer and interpreter. Upon class loading Ruby uses it’s lexer to parse the grammar. It does not execute anything on that stage, save for class-scoped constructs.

Comment: You could have answered your own question if you were prepared to wait a day. If you had had instead written `def eligible_to_vote?(time_of_interest = Time.now)` you'd only have to wait a nanosecond.

Comment: @CarySwoveland why waste a nanosecond waiting when you might instead spend just an hour writing a question and awaiting for the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dynamic because Ruby is interpreted, not compiled language.

```
✎ require 'date'
✎ def test param = DateTime.now
    puts param
  end
✎ 3.times { test; sleep(1) }
2018-12-14T18:10:08+01:00
2018-12-14T18:10:09+01:00
2018-12-14T18:10:10+01:00
```

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? Also, you are wrong: in fact, all currently existing Ruby interpretations have compilers.

Comment: I had never said there are no compilers.

Comment: Python too is an interpreted language but default values there are evaluated once, when the function is loaded. The evaluation time of default values has nothing to do with being a compiled or interpreted language.

Answer (score 7):

> What I'm mostly interested in is if default method arguments are dynamically generated or not.

It would be trivially easy to test this:

```
def are_default_arguments_evaluated_every_time?(optional_parameter = puts('YES!')) end

are_default_arguments_evaluated_every_time?
# YES!

are_default_arguments_evaluated_every_time?
# YES!
```

If default arguments were evaluated at method definition time, this would print `YES!` only once, and before calling the method. If default arguments were evaluated only on the first call and then cached, this would print `YES!` only once, when the method first gets called.

> Whatever the answer is, it would be nice to have some official reference to answer this question as well.

This is specified in section §13.3.3 *Method invocation*, step *h)*, sub-step *7)*, sub-sub-step *i)* of the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579).

Answer (score 0):

it's not static, Date.today is evaluated every time.

Take for example:

```
def foo(some_var = boo)
  p some_var
end

def boo
  p "this is boo"
  Date.today
end
```

When you run today

```
foo 
# "this is boo"
# Fri, 14 Dec 2018
foo 
# "this is boo"
# Fri, 14 Dec 2018
```

When you run tomorrow

```
foo 
# "this is boo"
# Fri, 15 Dec 2018
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how your code proves that the default argument `boo` is evaluated every time, as opposed to being statically set when you initially start your ruby program.

Comment: @Neil (edited it) Since it print out "this is boo" each time. (Boo returns 34, and print "this is boo")

Comment: I am still trying to understand your proof.  I am thinking about this in terms of ruby macros.  It seems to me that ruby looks at the method definition of `foo` when you start your ruby program, and that is why ruby notices if the method definition has any syntax errors in the method definition.  Whereas, you can have a bunch of syntax errors within the actual body of the method, but ruby will not pick up on this until you actually call the `foo` method, in which case it evaluates the code inside the method body.

Comment: @Neil you're right, ruby isn't compiled. When it loads the file, it only checks that `boo` is defined. Only when calling `foo` without args, it will evaluate `boo` and set the default value in `some_var`. You asked if `date_of_interest = Date.today` will call `Date.today` every time. It's like the example with `some_var = boo`. `boo` is like `Date.today`, some function, If it would be static, you would see the print "this is boo" only once, but it is printed every time you call `foo` since `boo` is evaluated each time. see my edit, `boo` returns time, maybe more related to your question